# Document CheckList and Einstein Form Reader Permission Sets not available on Winter'21 Preview Instance

Tags: standard-objects, permission-sets, automation, contentdocument, preview

I am trying out the **'Intelligent Document Automation'** feature that has come in Preview Instances of Winter'21 Release. For using this feature, there are certain Permission Sets, Settings that need to be made.
Some of them are present while others like 'Document Checklist' permission set, 'Einstein Form Reader' User Permission, 'OCR Document Scan Result', 'Document Type' 'Enable Einstein form reader' in the Setup are not available.

Am I missing something related to Setup on the Org.
Or does this got something to do with the Preview Instance and will be fixed once the Non-Preview instances are released.

**Link:** *https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_document_automation.htm*

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Einstein Form Reader Pilot in your orgs and contact Salesfoce AE for the same.

If you would like to try out Form Reader Capabilities, there is a Appexchange's managed package called "Extension for Einstein Form Reader" which is free of cost.

Below is the link for the AppExchange Product.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000PGQIBEA5